# Changing value in Copied Map reflecting in Original Map

Tags: apex, map

I am copying a Map from another Map. After the copying is done, I am changing the values in the new Map. However the new changes done in the new Map are also reflecting in the original Map.
Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

```
Map<String,List<String>> map1 = new Map<String,List<String>>();
Map<String,List<String>> map2 = new Map<String,List<String>>();

map1.put('abc',new List<String> {'123'});
map1.put('xyz',new List<String> {'0987'});

map2 = map1; // Even tried putall method here

for(String str1  :map2.keyset() ){
    map2.get(str1).add('extra value');
}
system.debug('map2===>>'+ map2); //{abc=(123, extra value), xyz=(0987, extra value)}
system.debug('map1===>>'+ map1); //{abc=(123, extra value), xyz=(0987, extra value)} -- extra value should not relect here
```

Comment: There are quite a few similar questions already answered in this forum, such as [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260299/pass-by-reference-vs-pass-by-value), [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262312/pass-by-reference) etc. Also, check [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/05/passing-parameters-by-reference-and-by-value-in-apex.html) out. Basically, assigning `map1` to `map2` is passing it by reference, which means that both point to the same memory location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not copying the map, but simply ensuring both variables are pointing to the same map. Copying a map can usually be done using `Map.clone` or `Map.deepClone`. However, neither of these ensures that the actual keys and values are themselves cloned (except when the values are SObjects). Since your keys are strings, there is no problem with the keys - strings are immutable. However, your values are lists which are mutable, so cloning a map will still reference the same lists in each value.

The solution is to manually "deep clone" the map (`Map.deepClone` only clones any SObjects that are the map values, which isn't the case here):

```
Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new Map<String, List<String>>();

for (String key : map1.keySet()) {
    List<String> value = map1.get(key);

    map2.put(key, value.clone());
}
```

Note how each value, a list, is cloned to ensure the new map has independent lists as its values that are initially populated with the same values.

If your lists actually contained mutable values you would have to clone the data more deeply, but since you have lists (mutable) of strings (immutable) the above is all you need do.